# Sort a list of tuples where each tuple is one string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of tuples where each tuple is a string:

```
lst1 = [('Lunch, Lisbon, 14:15, 10, 12',), ('Lunch, Paris, 13:10, 14, 06',), ('Dinner, Madrid, 13:50, 18, 10',)]
```

My list can be bigger than this and I want to sort it by time (3rd element of my string).
I thought of making each tuple a list and this is the code I used:

```
    for element in lst1:
        for x in element:
            wordlist = x.split(', ')
```

that gives me this output:

```
['Lunch', 'Lisbon', '14:15', '10', '12']
['Lunch', 'Paris', '13:10', '14', '06']
['Dinner', 'Madrid', '13:50', '18', '10']
```

So now I just need to sort this lists and put them back together sorted so I have the same thing I started with, a list of tuples where each tuple is a string.
I tried to use list.sort but that gave me an error.
I'm new to python and I have no idea of how to do this, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why do you have tuples with strings in them instead of just tuples or just strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `key` function

```
>>> lst1 = [('Lunch, Lisbon, 14:15, 10, 12',), ('Lunch, Paris, 13:10, 14, 06',), ('Dinner, Madrid, 13:50, 18, 10',)]
>>> sorted(lst1, key=lambda x:x[0].split(", ")[2])
[('Lunch, Paris, 13:10, 14, 06',), ('Dinner, Madrid, 13:50, 18, 10',), ('Lunch, Lisbon, 14:15, 10, 12',)]
```

example of a named key function

```
>>> def key_func(x):
...     return x[0].split(", ")[2]
... 
>>> key_func(('Lunch, Lisbon, 14:15, 10, 12',))  # test it
'14:15'
>>> sorted(lst1, key=key_func)
[('Lunch, Paris, 13:10, 14, 06',), ('Dinner, Madrid, 13:50, 18, 10',), ('Lunch, Lisbon, 14:15, 10, 12',)]
```

Comment: I have never heard of key functions before, can you please explain to me how that line of code works?

Comment: @Niennaz, a `key` function simply returns the value you are using for the sort comparison. For simple cases they are often written using the lambda syntax, although it's often better to write a normal named function as then it can be tested independently from the sort

Comment: @Niennaz - They are documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-key-function